# Set the width of a composite as a percentage of its container

Tags: gwt

I have a couple of composite widgets which all have dymaincally sizing object within them.

When I instantiate a composite widget I would like it to fill *its* container as a percentage, say 80% for example.

Each of the objects within the widget will grow to fit inside the composite regardless of composites size but the composite itself wont grow as a percentage of *its* container.

Is this even possible? I have tried the .setWidth() method but this won't recognise a % asd an argument.

---

I am not setting the size within the composite widget class.

I have a calling class that instantiates the composite widget and then calls the setWidth() method on the new object.

I will try out your method and if it works then apply it to my problem. I will post again once I have some more information.

Thankyou for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse it is possible.Composite setWidth() method recognizes % also.Can you give me the sample code you are using? Make sure that calling of setWidth() method must be after the initwidget() call of your composite.try like this

```
public class Widget1 extends Composite{
 private VerticaPanel panel=new VerticalPanel();
 public Widget1(){
   initWidget(panel);
   setWidth("80%");
   panel.add(new Widget2());
  }
} 

public class Widget2 extends Composite{
 private VerticaPanel panel=new VerticalPanel();
 public Widget2(){
   initWidget(panel);
   setWidth("100%");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test composite class:

```
 **class CompositePane extends Composite {
//Define a panel that contains everything
private VerticalPanel compositePanel = new VerticalPanel();
private Button button1 = new Button("Button1");


public CompositePane(){//Start StatusPane constructor

    compositePanel.add(button1);
    initWidget(compositePanel);
    setWidth("100%");
    addStyleName("compositePanel");

}//End of StatusPane constructor


}//End of StatusPane class**
```

Here is my style attached to this object that shows the edges of the composite object:

```
 .compositePanel{

 **border: 5px solid black;

}**
```

When using a set value of pixels the border expands as expected.

When using 100%, it sit tightly around the button, where I need it to touch the outside edge of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.Where you are adding this CompositePanel. CompositePanel.setWidth("100%") method makes this compositePanel to use it parents 100% width.So in your case its parent width is less.Try the following example .You will understand that what to do in your code.Now borders width will be 800px.

```
VerticalPanel parentPanel=new VerticalPanel();
parentPanel.setWidth("800");
parentPanel.add(new CompositePanel());
RootPanel.get().add(parentPanel);
```